# How can I code a VB Form Application to display different sets of input controls based upon the button clicked?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have tried placing my input controls in both group boxes and panel boxes and changing the .Visible property to True for the group/panel box the user selects, and all the others to false.

Am I barking up the wrong tree and thinking about this UI design wrong?  Here is the code I have written so far:

```
Public Class frmMainMenu

Dim blnIncident As Boolean = False
Dim blnPatient As Boolean = False
Dim blnAssessments As Boolean = False
Dim blnInterventions As Boolean = False
Dim blnNarrative As Boolean = False

Private Sub PanelFocus()

    If blnIncident = True Then

        pnlIncidentInfo.Visible = True
        pnlPatientInformation.Visible = False
        pnlAssessments.Visible = False
        pnlInterventions.Visible = False
        pnlNarrative.Visible = False

    ElseIf blnPatient = True Then

        pnlPatientInformation.Visible = True
        pnlIncidentInfo.Visible = False
        pnlAssessments.Visible = False
        pnlInterventions.Visible = False
        pnlNarrative.Visible = False

    ElseIf blnAssessments = True Then

        pnlAssessments.Visible = True
        pnlIncidentInfo.Visible = False
        pnlPatientInformation.Visible = False
        pnlInterventions.Visible = False
        pnlNarrative.Visible = False

    ElseIf blnInterventions = True Then

        pnlInterventions.Visible = True
        pnlIncidentInfo.Visible = False
        pnlAssessments.Visible = False
        pnlPatientInformation.Visible = False
        pnlNarrative.Visible = False

    ElseIf blnNarrative = True Then

        pnlNarrative.Visible = True
        pnlIncidentInfo.Visible = False
        pnlPatientInformation.Visible = False
        pnlAssessments.Visible = False
        pnlInterventions.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnIncident_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIncident.Click

    blnIncident = True
    PanelFocus()

End Sub


Private Sub btnPatientInfo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPatientInfo.Click

    blnPatient = True
    PanelFocus()

End Sub

Private Sub btnVitals_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVitals.Click
    blnAssessments = True
    PanelFocus()

End Sub

Private Sub btnInterventions_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInterventions.Click
    blnInterventions = True
    PanelFocus()

End Sub

Private Sub btnNarrative_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNarrative.Click
    blnNarrative = True
    PanelFocus()

End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks,

Scott

[edit]

I think I found the issue.  I inadvertently put some of the panel box controls inside each other, giving then a child relationship with the parent panel.  They wouldn't display because... the parent control had its visible property set to false.  I also forgot to set the boolean variable for the user's selection back to false after the sub call.

Thanks to those of you who took the time to read my question.  If you have a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, feel free to share or contact me.

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done probably works, but it will be hard to maintain. It would be better code to create a user control for each scenario.

Think about what properties each scenario has in common and define an interface.
Then have each user control implement the interface.

Its extra work at first - but will pay off heaps in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Since all your code is doing, is making one panel Visible while making all the others invisible.  One way to make it easier to understand your code later and make it quite a bit leaner, is to set the buttons' click events to be handled by the same handler.  Then in the handler,  iterate through the panels making them all invisible except for the one matching the clicked button, make it Visible

Something like this:

```
For Each btn as Button in Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
Next

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ClickedButton as Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    For Each p as Panel in Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
        If p.Name.Contains(ClickedButton.Name.Substring(3)) Then
            p.Visible = True
        Else
            p.Visible =False
        End If
End Sub
```

One other change you'll have to make, for this code to work, is change the name of btnVitals to btnAssessments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I will try this when I get to a place I can do some coding Monday after I get to Daytona.